# Dynamic routing based on external data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on an application that needs to configure routes based on some external data source. The life cycle of the app looks like this:

- ng2 inits with App
- App contains Header, router-outlet, and Footer
- default route is configured to homeComponent
- homeComponent has categoriesListComponent
- categoriesListComponent calls a get method from categoriesService
- categoriesService gets back a list of categories from the api
- categoriesComponent renders the list and injects new routes for each category back into App via a routesConfigurator

<sub>There's actually another layer of abstraction with a routesService but that isn't needed for this example</sub>

That part works, since we started at the home page, the API call was made and created the `routerConfigs` for each category. So when the user clicks on a category, the route is already configured with the correct `categoryComponent` + `metadata` and they're shown the correct information.

However, if a specific category page is accessed directly ng2 doesn't have the `routerConfig` for that route yet, since the API call hasn't returned anything, let alone fired off yet. Ng2 just renders the basic App with Header, Footer and an empty router-outlet.

The only solution I can think of is pretty "hacky". Keep a cached json file on the app server and load it up in the initial html, then inject that into a service at ng2 bootstrap/init. That way the routes are configured before ng2 even beings to render the page.

I'm asking for any other possible suggestions, perhaps someone with a bit more ng2 experience that me can chime in. Maybe this was solved already and I just haven't perfected my google-fu enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't notice any question in your content?!

Comment: `I'm asking for any other possible suggestions...`

Comment: ok, it's just too much to read, I just quickly scanned it for any question marks, didn't find any.

Comment: Router is still immature, though they just came up with the new NEW @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3 and are currently writing the docs for it.

Comment: I think that routes should be bound to component. If you have a single component that display different content depending on some API call, then make them route parameters (`/category/:categoryName`). You can learn much about the router at http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router.

Comment: Yea, I get that. However, it's the category names that come from an API call.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the new router (`>= RC.3`) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor `resetConfig` can be used to load new routes

> ```ts
> router.resetConfig([
>  { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
>    { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
>    { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
>  ] }
> ]);
> ```

You would have a custom `routerLink` directive or just some link or button that calls an event handler on click where new routes are loaded and then `router.navigate(...)` is called to navigate to the appropriate route.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437#issuecomment-245995186 provides an **RC.6** Plunker

Comment: components still need import statements to import all routes at top of the component. which actually kills the purpose of dynamic route

Comment: There is `loadChildren`. I don't know how well it is working already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837493/angular2-rc-4-layz-routing

Comment: The link to resetConfig api gives 404

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer where should this code be paced? I have pretty similar problem, but I need to call an injected service to find the allowed routes https://stackoverflow.com/q/47793774/2065796

Comment: You can inject the router to that service, then you can call `resetConfig` https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if one of the above comments is your solution of the result that you wanted but I have a new method that might be interested in you and other developers out there.

I created a javascript file where I add my routes.

```
"use strict";
const home_component_1 = require("location javascript component file");
exports.DYNAMIC_ROUTES = [
    { path: '', component: your_component_name_component_1.YourComponentName },
]
```

Then in the `app.routing.ts` (your routing file), you will have to add an **import** statement to your javascript file

```
// JAVASCRIPT IMPORT
import { DYNAMIC_ROUTES } from 'location javascript file';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: NormalLayoutComponent, children: DYNAMIC_ROUTES },
]
```

Hereby by doing this method you now can manipulate the javascript file with Typescript for dynamic changes. You can even create the file by php and then keep it in the same place. Notice you need to have an already compiled component in my case there is one and it handles all the routes in one component for me.

Also, make sure if you are using a compiler that removes your javascript make sure to read them to the build folder or make sure it compiles with your application.