# angular2 rc.4 layz routing

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

Angular2 rc.4 lazy Routing is depreciated.

[Async Routing example](https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/02/09/angular2-quicky-async-routes/)

is there any new lazy routing / async routing example for rc.4

Answer (score 5):

`loadChildren` is supposed to do that:

```
{
  path: 'section',
  loadChildren: 'section-bundle'
}
```

I don't know what exactly the string should point to.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9527#issuecomment-236038503
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10577 (with Plunker)

```
{ path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module' }
```

Comment: won't solve my problem i need some thing like this new AsyncRoute({
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    loader: () => {
      return System.import('app/components/about/about')
        .then(m=> m.AboutComponent);
    }
  })

Comment: please check following question, i kinda resolve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860071/angular2-programmatically-import-components-from-resource-files