# angular2 dynamic routes run time component import

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 2 rc.4

I have dynamic routes JSON defined in routes variable. problem i have only with components.I still have to import all components using import statement and have them in top of the file in order to use them, which actually kills the purpose of dynamic routing.

i have seen some examples like where people trying to do System.import('component_file_name') which uses AsyncRoute is already deprecated. its kinda show stopper any solutions suggestion is appreciated in advance

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {IncComponent} from './inc.component';
import {AdditionComponent} from './addition.component';
import {RomanComponent} from './roman.component';
declare var System:any;

import {AjaxRequestService} from './ajax.req.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl:'app/app.html',
    providers: [
        AjaxRequestService,
    ],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router){

    let routes: RouterConfig = [
            {
                path: 'increment',
                component: IncComponent
            },{
                path: 'adder',
                component: AdditionComponent
            },{
                path: 'roman',
                component: RomanComponent
            }

        ];

        router.resetConfig(routes);
    }

    title = 'Angular 2 Demo Applications';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadChildren` like

```
{ path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module' }
```

See also [angular2 rc.4 layz routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837493/angular2-rc-4-layz-routing)

Comment: router.resetConfig(routeConfigArr); it takes routeConfig Array and roueConfig does not have property loadChildren, how i going to work

Comment: `RouteConfig` doesn't but the routes added to `RouteConfig`.

Comment: sorry i didn't get that will you please elaborate a little bit more

Comment: The code in my answer is a single route. The route config consists of a list of such routes and the routes do have the `loadChildren`.

Comment: children based routes architecture not gona solve my problem.

Comment: I need some thing like new AsyncRoute({
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    loader: () => {
      return System.import('app/components/about/about')
        .then(m=> m.AboutComponent);
    }
  }) but Async class is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

I have rc5 version to share with you:
http://plnkr.co/edit/18CZVF?p=preview

After using AppModule, loadChildren still the same as:

```
{ path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module' }
```