# Redirect to first allowed route in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, roles

I have following route configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'customers', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'customers', component: CustomerListComponent, canActivate: [CustomerGuard] },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent, canActivate: [ProductGuard] },
  { path: 'sales', component: SalesListComponent, canActivate: [SalesGuard] }
];
```

The problem is, I have no 'dashbord', only domain management pages, and although every authorized user will have access to at least one of them, none of them will be available to all user.

Is there an option to say: redirect to first route, that can be activated? Or I need to write a virtual component under path '/' that would do dynamic redirection, based on user roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to redirect to the first available route.
Using a dummy route with a dummy component that just redirects depending on the role is the way to go. You can also do the redirect in a guard https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards but the dummy route would need a component anyway.

What you can also do is use `router.resetConfig()` to load routes depending on the role as shown in [Dynamic routing based on external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data/38096468#38096468)

Comment: So this is what I thought, I need to create a role to 'dummy' component which will redirect me somewhere, but this dummy component doesn't have to be visual (template etc)?

Comment: You can just use `template: ''`. I have one `DummyComponent` in each project just to be able to list a component where required by the router but not by me. AFAIR there was recently a pull request so that a component is not required anymore in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to the first route that can be activated within a component like `MyComponent`, you can dynamically modify the route object corresponding to this component. Here's how you can do it:

```js
// Import ActivatedRoute and Router modules to access the current route and navigate
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

// Inside the constructor of MyComponent
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

// Inside the ngOnInit() method
ngOnInit() {
  // Get the child routes
  const childRoutes = this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.children;

  // Find the first child route with permissions
  const firstRouteWithPermissions = childRoutes.find(route => {
    const permissions = route.data?.permissions?.only;
    return permissions && permissions.length > 0;
  });

  // If a route with permissions is found, navigate to it
  if (firstRouteWithPermissions) {
    const path = firstRouteWithPermissions.path;
    this.router.navigate([path], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
  }
}
```

This code searches among the child routes of `MyComponent` for the first route that has defined permissions and navigates to it.