# How do I change the base URL dynamically in Angular 2 routing?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

Currently, I have routing set up in my project. Every new user is redirected to:

> localhost:4200/default-path/login

Once the user logs in, they're redirected to the home module, which has some child routes the user can navigate to.

> localhost:4200/default-path/**home**
>   localhost:4200/default-path/**home/account**
>   localhost:4200/default-path/**home/account/profile**
>   localhost:4200/default-path/**home/dashboard**

... and so on.

Now, the part in bold is already set up in the home module, and doesn't need further editing. However, I'd like to change `default-path` to something else.

Say, each user can belong to one of three projects: Project blue, red or green. This information is available *only after* the user submits their credentials and hits the login button.

What I'd like for the routes to say *after login* is:

> localhost:4200/**project-blue**/home
>   localhost:4200/**project-red**/home
>   localhost:4200/**project-green**/home

Bear in mind, the parts in bold are NOT different modules with different associated components, they're just constants I'd like to see in the URL.

Currently, my `<base>` tag in the index is like `<base href='/'>` I'm trying to edit this attribute. What I've got is something like:

```
processLoginSuccess(loginTicket): void {
    const routeName = loginTicket.baseUrl // returns 'project-red'
    let b = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]
    b.setAttribute('href', routeName )

    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data/38096468#38096468

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: That looks like it resets the config for the child routes. I need to edit my base url. Can I do that with resetConfig?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to modify the base url

Comment: i think dynamic router link can be set up in router configuration for children routes of projects route.

Comment: @vishal: That's good to hear. Do you have a link or a plunker or something I could refer to?

Comment: something like this `const projectsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ProjectsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':projectName/home',
                component: ProjectHomeComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setting the `base` element's `href` value, you can set the base URL programmatically, by providing for `APP_BASE_HREF` with your custom operation.

This has been already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41674411/415790