# Dynamically register the route data in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my case routing data are available in Database. So i need to take the value from Database and create routing dynamically at run time. I didn't find any option to load a route data before route init or pause the application until route data load.

Please suggest me a idea

Comment: How complex are your routes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data/38096468#38096468

Comment: https://github.com/mgechev/dynamic-route-creator/blob/master/app/components/app/app.ts

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes we can reset but i need to pause the application until route data get from service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think above URL help. Let try to achieve my requirement.

Comment: A combination of both suggestions should do it.

Answer (score 0):

**If** your routes are not complex:

You can define routes with 'variables':

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'news/:id', component: MyComponent },
])
```

The official documentation about the Router is available [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)