# Can we modify routing or can we able to modify root level route(e.g. app.route.ts)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My Requirement is:
Can we modify routing defined in root level app.routing file and then can we able to navigate specific child route through code(typescript) in angular-2?

Can some one help me here?

Comment: What does stop routing mean?

Comment: @smnbbrv, i have edited the question, sorry to used wrong-word.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to other route in code

```
constructor(private router:Router) {}

someEventHandlerOrWhatever() {
  this.router.navigate('/otherroute');
}
```

and I guess what you mean with stop routing is named guards

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Your question also sounds a bit like [Dynamic routing based on external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data/38096468#38096468)