# Angular4 - Router module provider AOT

Tags: angular, aot

This is my declaration of the router provider:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(RoutesFactory.buildRoutes())],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RouterModuleProvider { };
```

Compiling in AOT, I get this error:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function
>   'getRoutes', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the
>   function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving
>   symbol RouterModuleProvider

Here is the content of RoutesFactory.buildRoutes

```
static buildRoutes() {
    let returnRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'login', component: ViewsModule.LoginViewComponent }
    ];

    let appendRoutes = (items: MenuItem[], routes: Routes) => {
        for (let item of items) {
            let route: Route = {
                path: item.Path, component: item.Component, children: []
            };

            if (item.Children != null)
                appendRoutes(item.Children, route.children)

            routes.push(route);
        }
    };

    appendRoutes(RoutesFactory.getMenus(), returnRoutes);

    return returnRoutes;

}
```

RoutesFactory.getMenus() returns a static internal array of objects. (nothing loaded from backend)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you have in RoutesFactory.buildRoutes() ?

Comment: I edited my own question in order to give more details about the issue

Comment: This looks like a really weird way of doing aot routing. Any reason you do this?

Comment: It's pointing to the function 'getRoutes' in the error, where are you calling that>

Comment: @mast3rd3mon The reason is that I create routing based on my menu objects. That's the only reason. I'm open to any suggestion

Comment: it would be best practice to create your menu objects based on your routing file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as the error suggests, everything that is part of the metadata (inside `@NgModule(...)` declaration) has to be statically resolvable. This means that there cannot be any logic like you have in your `buildRoutes` function, only static declarations.

However, there seems to be an alternative specifically for defining routes dynamically. Please see this answer: [Dynamic routing based on external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data).

Comment: I'll take a look at your suggestion. Thanks for the tip.