# $routeProvider route params from database

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I want to load fill the route params with data from database.

For example, I have

```
$routeProvider.when('/:param1/:param2', loadParams())
```

And loadParams function

```
function loadParams() {
    var data = {
        path: window.location.pathname
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getRouteParams',
        data: data,
        success: function(data, status) {
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.controller = data.controller;
            attributes.templateUrl = data.templateUrl;
            return attributes;
        }
    });
}
```

But this function give me an error

```
Cannot read property 'reloadOnSearch' of undefined
```

Comment: Would need info on versions to know if this helps?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data

Comment: I'm using angular 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself

The solution is deactivate the async and put the return out of the "success"

```
function loadParams() {
    var data = {
        path: window.location.pathname
    };
    var attributes = {};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getRouteParams',
        data: data,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, status) {
            attributes.controller = data.controller;
            attributes.templateUrl = data.templateUrl;
        }
    });
    return attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where you use reloadsearch property in routeprovider,i don't find in your code.
[reloadOnSearch=true] - {boolean=} - reload route when only $location.search() or $location.hash() changes.

If the option is set to false and url in the browser changes, then $routeUpdate event is broadcasted on the root scope.

Comment: I don't use "reloadOnSearch" in any part of my code

Comment: use reloadOnSearch:false option