# angular 8 dynamic routing from database

Tags: angular, routes, frontend, backend

I am trying to get a set of routes from the backend and then put them into the file app.routing.module.ts so that I can be able to navigate to the routes fetched. Instead of navigating like this:

```
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent,
  },
```

I want to get those informations (those paths and the component of each path) from the DB.
I tried to look for a method of how I can do that but I couldn't find anything helpful. Can you please tell me if it is possible to do so? and if it is, then how can I do that?

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756167/dynamic-routing-based-on-external-data