# Angular router: navigating to different routes according to the user's role

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-routing, user-roles, angular-guards

I'm writing a mock e-commerce app which has the following structure:

- app

  - auth

    - sign-in-page
    - sign-up-page
    - **auth-routing.module.ts**

      ```js
      const routes: Routes = [
        {
          path: 'signup',
          component: SignUpPage,
        },
        {
          path: 'signin',
          component: SignInPage,
        },
      ];
      ```
    - **auth.module.ts**
  - admin

    - root-page
    - **admin-routing.module.ts**

      ```js
      const routes: Routes = [
        {
          path: 'admin',
          component: RootPage,
          children: [
            // ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          ],
        },
      ];
      ```
    - **admin.modules.ts**
  - customer

    - root-page
    - catalog-page
    - check-out-page
    - thank-you-page
    - **customer-routing.module.ts**

      ```js
      const routes: Routes = [
        {
          path: 'customer',
          component: RootPage,
          children: [
            { path: 'catalog/:categoryId', component: CatalogPage },
            { path: 'checkout', component: CheckOutPage },
            { path: 'thankyou', component: ThankYouPage },
          ],
        },
      ];
      ```
    - **customer.module.ts**
  - page-not-found
  - **app-routing.module.ts**

    ```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundPage },
    ];
    ```
  - **app.module.ts**
  - **app.component.html**
  - **app.component.css**

The basic workflow is supposed to be as follows:

0. The user navigates to the root path `/`.
1. The application detects that they are not logged in, so it redirects them to `/signin`.
2. They enter their credentials and press **Sign In**.
3. If the authentication is successful,

   1. If the user is an admin, they get redirected to `/admin`.

      1. `admin-router.module.ts` redirects them to some sub-path of `/admin`.
   2. If the user is a customer, they get redirected to `/customer`.

      1. `customer-router.module.ts` redirects them to `/customer/catalog/<default category ID>`.
      2. They put some products in the shopping cart and proceed to `/customer/checkout`.
      3. They place the order and get redirected to `/customer/thankyou`.

What I'm not sure about is how to accomplish the redirection following a successful log-in. Obviously it has to be done in two stages: first to some common path such as `/` and then either to `/customer` or to `/admin` depending on the user's role. The second stage probably needs to be handled by `app-routing.module.ts`, perhaps using a guard, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

#### EDIT (2021-04-20)

The problem can be summarized as follows:

What I need is a way (preferably declarative) to redirect the application from `/` to one of the following paths depending on its state:

| State | Path |
| --- | --- |
| Logged out | `/auth` |
| Logged in as a *customer* | `/customer` |
| Logged in as an *admin* | `/admin` |

Comment: For the second part I think you should better use a `resolver` that will return the data you need.

Comment: Also take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096468/5107490

Comment: Why don't you plainly router.navigate to either /admin or /customer after the user is authenticated?

Comment: @c_froehlich Obviously this will work, but it will create undesirable coupling between the sign-in page and the rest of the app. To put it less theoretically: in any case, I need to redirect requests by an already logged-in user either to `/customer` or to `/admin`, so there's no reason to implement this redirection separately for the case where the user has just logged in.

Comment: May be use guard at level app and  then decided where to redirect

Comment: @RonInbar I see.  Usually I define an emitter which fires a next event whenever the user "state" changes (logged in, logged out). A "InitialPageService" can subscribe to this event and do the redirection.  This way it's not bound to a particular route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this:

```js
// app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard],
    children: [],
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundPage },
];
```

```js
// authorization.guard.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthorizationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): UrlTree {
    const user = this.authService.getLoggedInUser();
    return (
      (user?.role === 'admin' && this.router.parseUrl('/admin')) ||
      (user?.role === 'customer' && this.router.parseUrl('/customer')) ||
      this.router.parseUrl('/auth')
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: So basically, you did as I suggested?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Basically, yes, but there are some subtle differences. For one, the `/admin` and `/customer` routes are defined in separate modules. Also, as I pointed out in my earlier comment, I didn't use a dummy component.

Comment: I don't see routes for `/admin` and `/customer` defined here so I don't think it technically answers your question. Also - your current guard has more than one responsibility and might be best served as two guards. When you see something like `AdminGuard` in `app-routing.module.ts` you would know exactly what it's doing instead of something like `AuthenticationAndRouteBasedAuthorizationGuard`. Anyway, glad you found a solution that didn't require a dummy component.

Comment: @Dean Refer to the original question. The `/admin` and `/customer` routes are defined in their respective modules.

Answer (score 3):

You could create some dummy component and protect it with a guard that handles the correct navigation. Something like this:

```
[
  {
    path: 'loggedin',
    component: DummyComponent,
    canActivate: [HandleLoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'customer',
    component: CustomerComponent,
  }
]


@Injectable()
class HandleLoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    if(isAdmin()){
        route.navigate(/admin);
    }else{
        route.navigate(/customer);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This way you can put the logic in a guard instead of the login component.

Comment: Actually there's no need for a dummy component. You can define a component-less route with an empty `children` array.